# Integer overflow and integer limits

Tags: c++, integer, overflow, limits

I am a novice please help me to understand INTEGER OVERFLOW and working with INTEGER LIMITS in context of the following example.
I am unable to interpret the output of the following code.
I have considered three cases, directly printing , integers and unsigned long long integer.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<limits.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int tmp1=0,tmp2=0,tmp3=0,tmp4=0;
unsigned long long temp1=0,temp2=0,temp3=0,temp4=0;

cout<<"Directly printing"<<endl;

cout<<-2*INT_MIN<<endl<<2*INT_MIN<<endl<<-2*INT_MAX<<endl<<2*INT_MAX<<endl;

cout<<"Using integer"<<endl;

tmp1 = -2*INT_MIN;
tmp2 = 2*INT_MIN;
tmp3 = -2*INT_MAX;
tmp4 = 2*INT_MAX;

cout<<temp1<<endl<<tmp2<<endl<<tmp3<<endl<<tmp4<<endl;

cout<<"Using unsigned long long variables"<<endl;

temp1 = -2*INT_MIN;
temp2 = 2*INT_MIN;
temp3 = -2*INT_MAX;
temp4 = 2*INT_MAX;

cout<<temp1<<endl<<temp2<<endl<<temp3<<endl<<temp4;
}
```

### OUTPUT:

```
Directly printing
0
0
2
-2
Using integer
0
0
2
-2
Using unsigned long long variables
0
0
2
18446744073709551614
```

Comment: `<limits.h>` is the C header, not that it matters, but you might want to take a look at `<limits>` that has e.g. `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()`

Comment: You have *undefined behavior* in your code, you use the `unsigned long long` variables before they are initialized. In the "Using integer" section you print the values of `temp1` etc., when you should be using `tmp1` etc. Try to use better variable-naming and these things hopefully won't happen that much. Also, a good compiler would have issued warnings about this.

Comment: Sounds a lot like "do my homework for me".  What relevant facts have you found so far?  What specifically don't you understand?  Is there anything specifically in the output that strikes you as unexpected?  Draft C++ Standards papers are easily available online - did you try to understand anything about the limits or behaviours during overflow?  Even if that's too daunting, specific questions can be researched on S.O..

Comment: I am unable to understand the output. If you have some reference to C++ standard papers kindly share them

Answer (score 1):

`tmp1 = -2*INT_MIN;` undefined behaviour unless INT_MAX has twice the magnitude of INT_MIN (it won't).

`tmp2 = 2*INT_MIN;` undefined behaviour (overflowing a signed integer)

`tmp3 = -2*INT_MAX;` undefined behaviour unless INT_MIN has twice the magnitude of INT_MAX (it won't).

`tmp4 = 2*INT_MAX;` undefined behaviour (overflowing a signed integer)

`temp1 = -2*INT_MIN;` undefined behaviour (overflowing a signed integer)

`temp2 = 2*INT_MIN;` undefined behaviour (overflowing a signed integer)

`temp3 = -2*INT_MAX;` undefined behaviour (overflowing a signed integer)

`temp4 = 2*INT_MAX;` undefined behaviour (overflowing a signed integer)

Comment: "signed arithmetic with unsigned type" is simply promotion of signed value to unsigned is it not? And isn't that well defined (`[conv.integral]
`)?

Comment: @user2079303 you're right. gcc is giving me "25 : warning: integer overflow in expression [-Woverflow]" for that line.

Comment: Indeed, those lines have the same undefined behaviour of overflowing the signed integer in the multiplication, as the lines above. `INT_MAX` and `2` are both signed.

Comment: I think the last bit is a bit redundant. All of the signed multiplications overflow (except `-2*INT_MAX` in the non-existing corner case) and have UB. All the assignments to unsigned would be well defined, whether the signed integer is in a representable range or not.